# Structuring my data - Firebase

Tags: database, firebase

I'm creating a prototype group list application. I want the following objects:

- User
- List
- Item
- Comment

I think that I should structure this as follows:

```
http://myapp.firebase.io/user/
http://myapp.firebase.io/user/uid/lists/
http://myapp.firebase.io/list/
http://myapp.firebase.io/item/listid/
http://myapp.firebase.io/comment/itemid
```

where http://myapp.firebase.io/user/uid/lists/ points to list unique id's, http://myapp.firebase.io/item/listid/ points to all item objects for a given list, and http://myapp.firebase.io/comment/itemid points to all comments for a given item.

Does this structure make sense? The reason I did it this way instead of nesting further (i.e. http://myapp.firebase.io/list/listid/item/ for items and http://myapp.firebase.io/list/listid/item/itemid/comment for comments) is because it says in the documentation that whenever you fetch an object you fetch all children. Sometimes (perhaps even most of the time) I want to fetch a list's items, but not each item's comments. I might only want to do that when a user clicks on the item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a NoSQL database you should model your data for how you intend to use it. I highly recommend reading this [article on NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

The top-level structure seems fine and does not violate [Firebase's recommendation to limit nesting of data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html). But there are many other places where you might still make mistakes (which is one of the reasons this question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow, but I'll try to answer some of it anyway).

I'd separate out the user's lists into a separate top-level node:

```
/userlists/$uid/$listid
```

That way the `/users/$uid` nodes would just contain the user's profile information and you could cheaply show a list of users. You might even consider splitting the most visible aspect of the user profile into another top-level node, to make the showing of such a list even cheaper.

```
/usernames/$uid
```

You'll be duplicating data in this case. But storage is (relatively) cheap, and optimizing for the more common reading of data is one of the reasons NoSQL databases can scale so well.

As you may notice, I focus on showing a list of user names, retrieving the lists for a user and accessing the profile for a specific user. These are use-cases and we're modeling the data to fit them.

In a NoSQL database you should **model your data for how your app accesses it**. I highly recommend reading this [article on NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

After that, write out your list of use-cases and see how you can most easily access the data for it. Liberally [denormalize](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-indices) and occasionally duplicate the data, to fit the use-cases. Use [multi-location updates](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-07-how-to-keep-your-data-consistent.html) to keep denormalized and duplicated data in sync with its main entity.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, Frank, and for the link to that resource. I'll give it a read :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer with some useful resources.