# Firebase Chat - Notification to Other User

Tags: swift, firebase, chat

I am currently building an app using Firebase, and decided to implement a chat as well.

I was able to use JSQMessagesVC as a GUI, and get the Firebase chat aspect working as well (by combining 2 UID's to create a chatroom, ex: /123_456). However, I am lost on how to notify the other user if they have received a message. (If user 123 opens chatroom 123_456 and sends a message in it, how do I notify user 456 that they have received a message?)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more related to designing your database. In case implementing chat functionalities you need to rethink about your database structure again. Its all about database structure as Firebase doesn't provide you any trigger so that you can do some actions on other nodes (i.e. database tables) with your primary action in the node you're in.

Though you might've read all those tutorials already, you can take a look again anyway about [structuring your data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/structuring-data.html)

Here's a nice [chat example](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat) which might help you in your case. Though its referring to a group chat. You might take a look at how the database is structured for this purpose.

Basically, you need to put some extra actions from client side in different nodes when someone opens a room to chat with others.

Oh here's another [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36392870/3145960) you should take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, which I solved by putting in an additional node where each user has a number of chatrooms. put an observer on the user in the chatroom (in below case "0888a5dc-fe8d-4498-aa69-f9dd1361fe54"), with a counter, a description and a timestamp. each new message, update counter, and lastMessage, etc. see below:

```
 "Messages" : {
"0888a5dc-fe8d-4498-aa69-f9dd1361fe54" : {
  "0888a5dc-fe8d-4498-aa69-f9dd1361fe5451879163-8b35-452b-9872-a8cb4c84a6ce" : {
    "counter" : 2,
    "description" : "Breta",
    "lastMessage" : “cool”,
    "lastUser" : "51879163-8b35-452b-9872-a8cb4c84a6ce",
    "messageType" : "txt",
    "sortTimestamp" : -1.459518501758476E9,
    "updatedAction" : 1.459518501758468E9,
    "userId" : "51879163-8b35-452b-9872-a8cb4c84a6ce"
  },
  "0888a5dc-fe8d-4498-aa69-f9dd1361fe547bfe8604-58ad-4d18-a528-601b76dd2206" : {
    "counter" : 0,
    "description" : "Romeo",
    "lastMessage" : “yep”,
    "lastUser" : "0888a5dc-fe8d-4498-aa69-f9dd1361fe54",
    "messageType" : "txt",
    "sortTimestamp" : -1.459527387138615E9,
    "updatedAction" : 1.459527387138613E9,
    "userId" : "7bfe8604-58ad-4d18-a528-601b76dd2206"
  }
}
```